# How to write jasmine test case for checking Toggle class functionality inside click event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine

I have one directive that basically does the class toggling on element. Its working fine. But Something wrong with jasmine test case of it.

```
//toggling class
fileSearch.directive('toggleClass', function() {
   return {
     restrict: 'A',
     link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind('click', function() {
            element.toggleClass(attrs.toggleClass);
        });
    }
};
```

});

Jasmine test Case :

```
describe(
    'testing toggle-class directive',
    function() {
        var $compile, $rootScope;
        beforeEach(module('myApp'));

        beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_) {
            $compile = _$compile_;
            $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        }));

        it('should set highlight class on report title',
                function() {
                    var element = $compile("<div toggleclass='highlighted'</div>")($rootScope);
                    element.click();
                    expect(element).toHaveClass('highlighted');
                });

    });
```

its throwing error by saying undefined  is not a constructor at line "  expect(element).toHaveClass('highlighted');"
Could you please guide me on this. I am somewhat new to angular.

Answer (score 2):

`toHaveClass` is not part of `Jasmine`.
Try something like :

```
expect(element.attr('class')).toEqual('highlighted');
```

I have plunkered [your code here](http://plnkr.co/edit/gi6YLuyFZxE5hhK5CTuP).

Comment: thanks man!!!. bdw checking class through attribute does not work it seems
I used hasClass !.
 expect(element.hasClass('highlighted')).toBe(true);

Comment: @BharatSewani checking the class attribute works. The test runs successfully . Please recheck the plunkr. What Jasmine version are you using ?